# How to list files with words exceeding n characters in all subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell

I have to write a shell script that creates a file containing the name of each text files from a folder (given as parameter) and it's subfolders that contain words longer than n characters (read n  from keyboard).

I wrote the following code so far :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

## Verifies if the first given parameter is a folder:

```
if [ ! -d $1 ]
then echo $1 is not a directory\!
exit 1
fi
```

## Reading n

```
echo -n "Give the number n: "
read n
echo "You entered: $n"
```

## Destination where to write the name of the files:

```
destinatie="destinatie"
```

## the actual part that i think it makes me problems:

```
nr=0;
#while read line; 
#do
for fisier in `find $1 -type f`
    do  
        counter=0
        for word in $(<$fisier);
            do
                file=`basename "$fisier"`
                length=`expr length $word`
                echo "$length"
                if [ $length -gt $n ];
                    then counter=$(($counter+1))
                fi
            done 
    if [ $counter -gt $nr ];
    then echo "$file" >> $destinatie
    fi
    done
break           
done
exit
```

The script works but it does a few more steps that i don't need.It seems like it reads some files more than 1 time. If anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
egrep -lr "\w{$n,}" $1/* >$destinatie
```

Some explanation:

`\w` means: a character that words consist of

`{$n,}` means: number of consecutive characters is at least `$n`

Option `-l` lists files and does not print the grepped text and `-r` performs a recursive scan on your directory in `$1`

---

Edit:

a bit more complete version around the egrep command:

```
#!/bin/bash

die() { echo "$@" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }

[ -z "$1" ] && die "which directory to scan?"

dir="$1"
[ -d "$dir" ] || die "$dir isn't a directory"

echo -n "Give the number n: "
read n
echo "You entered: $n"
[ $n -le 0 ] && die "the number should be > 0"

destinatie="destinatie"
egrep -lr "\w{$n,}" "$dir"/* | while read f; do basename "$f"; done >$destinatie
```

Comment: what exactly i should replace with the line you wrote? i'm new to shell and i didn't understood exactly what i have to replace

Comment: ...the block after `destinatie="destinatie"`

Comment: i tried it and works just fine ,but it prints the entire path.Any way to print just the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

- This code has syntax errors, probably leftovers from your commented-out `while` loop: It would be best to remove the last 3 lines: `done` causes the error, `break` and `exit` are unnecessary as there is nothing to break out from and the program always terminates at its end.
- The program appears to output files multiple times because you just append to `$destinatie`. You could simply delete that file when you start:

  ```
  rm "$destinatie"
  ```
- You echo the numbers to stdout (`echo "$length"`) and the file names to `$destinatie` (`echo "$file" >> $destinatie`). I do not know if that is intentional.

Comment: for the first point:  if i don't use break it will not terminate bi itself and i need to enter ctrl+c every time i run the script . for the second one: i manually deleted the file destinatie before every run , but rm "$destinatie"  makes my job easy. and for the third :  in the problem does not request to echo the length.i did that just to make sure that the program works,and that thing told me that it doesn't .

Comment: i saw that i forgot to comment the break and done , yes these are leftovers from while. I do not necesarily need the while read line? Is it ok just with the for loop?

Comment: @DamianAlex: You tell me if it is ok :-) In my short test it looks ok, the files that are below the threshold are written to the `destinatie` file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.The problem was the directory in which i was searching.Because i worked on the files from the direcotry and modified them , it seems that there remained some files which were not displayed in file explorer but the script would find them.i created another directory and i gived it as parameter and it works. Thank you for your answers
.