# Script to sort lines in a created file

Tags: bash, file, sorting, lines

I have a script that creates a file and writes something in it.

What instructions I must include in the same script so that the lines in that file will be sorted alphabetically?

Let me be more explicit, this is my code:

```
nr=0
while read line; 
do
    for fisier in `find $1 -type f`
        do  
            counter=0
            for word in $(<$fisier)
                do
                    file=`basename "$fisier"`
                    length=`expr length $word`
                    echo "$length"
                    if [ $length -gt $n ];
                        then counter=$(($counter+1))
                    fi
                done 
        if [ $counter -gt $nr ];
        then echo "$file" >> $destinatie
        fi
        done
break
done
```

Where exactly must I put the `| sort` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe your output through `sort`. If you have more than just a single command that creates the output, you can use a subshell like this:

```
(
# cmd 1
# cmd 2
) | sort > outfile
```

Using a while loop like your edited question, I would suggest just adding it after the `done` keyword:

```
while condition
do
  # ...
done | sort >> "$destinatie"
```

Note that you also have to remove the redirections `>> $destinatie` inside your loop and echo your debugging output to stderr instead:

```
>&2 echo "$length"
```

Also, because you are appending using `>>`, if you do not `rm $destinatie`on startup (which I remember you do as you indicated in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193355/how-to-list-files-with-words-exceeding-n-characters-in-all-subdirectories/29194925#29194925)), then the whole file will *not* be sorted after termination, instead only the lines added during each run will be sorted.

Read more about `sort`'s options using `man sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sort` Unix command:

```
function_generating_lines | sort > output_file.txt
```